# Google Sign-In Stopped Working on Pythonanywhere Domain. Permission Denied Error

Tags: python-3.x, google-signin, permission-denied, pythonanywhere

I was able to successfully integrate Google Sign-In on my website using the below standard code (with relevant inputs) (see [Integrating Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)). 2 Months later, with no changes to the code, google started throwing the following authorisation error during login:

> Error 400: invalid_request Permission denied to generate login hint
> for target domain.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
}
```

It seems this error is typically caused by incorrectly specifying `Authorized JavaScript origins` on the Google Cloud Platform, but I have used the actual URL to my website.

I have tried clearing cache

I ran the same code on localhost, using the same google client id (plus additional `Authorized JavaScript origins` setting) and it worked fine.

The host server is https://www.pythonanywhere.com/ and I have been testing my site on google chrome and safari.

Other users are having exactly the same issues on this domain, so I presume this is a domain related issue?